# Probability of measuring velocity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

In a one dimensional problem in quantum mechanics, does the probability of measuring momentum greater than $p_0$ correspond to the probability of measuring velocity greater than $v_0= \frac{p_0}{m}$?

Comment: Does your system consist of a single particle with fixed mass $m$? If so, then yes.